# How can we resolve a problem of datasource url attribute for a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, spring-data-jpa

I have launch my application an I received this error :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.2.1)[0;39m

[2m2024-01-09T10:21:04.750+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.demo.AppApplication         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting AppApplication using Java 17.0.9 with PID 8256 (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4\App\target\classes started by Admin in C:\Users\Admin\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4\App)
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:04.764+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.demo.AppApplication         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:07.178+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:07.267+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 53 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:09.237+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:09.294+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:09.296+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.17]
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:09.613+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:09.615+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4553 ms
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:10.030+01:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:10.043+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:10.122+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2024-01-09T10:21:10.197+01:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m8256[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I have done any configurations i my application.properties

I'm a trying to learn how to do a spring boot application

Comment: the problem is about the database configuration properties, could you please provide your config in `application.properties` ?

Comment: Well you decided to use Spring Data JPA, which requires a database. You neither configured a URL nor have included an embedded atabase in your dependencies. So what do you think should happen?

Answer (score 0):

As the **Description** in the error log says:

> Consider the following:
> If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

#### Option 1

You're just started developing your application and wanted to get up and running as quickly as possible - add an in-memory database library to your project's dependencies. Like adding [H2 Database](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) to your `pom.xml`'s `<dependencies>` section:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This setup should work without any additional configuration.
You fulfilled what the description asked for: *please put it on the classpath*.

Please bear in mind, never use an in-memory database in this fashion on production.

#### Add an External Database to Your Project

As a more robust solution, add an external database, like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/). Using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), add this dependency to your `<dependencies>` section:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

With this setup, you need to [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-install.html), configure and run a PostgreSQL instance locally or remotely.

If you have a working instance, one thing is left: configure your Spring Application to connect to the PostgreSQL instance.

Create or open your `application.properties` file in `src/main/resources` and add the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres-user
spring.datasource.password=postgres-password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Please replace the default values like `localhost`, `5432`, `posgres-user` and `postgres-password` with actual values if they are different on your setup (probably they are).

Certainly, you do not need to use the aforementioned database engines, they're just examples. Do your research and choose a database which fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties file you have to have this lines:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName:...
spring.datasource.url:...
spring.datasource.username:...
spring.datasource.password:...
```

After that you should add in your pom.xml the proper dependencies for your database.
Just look up for how to use H2 database with SpringBoot.
As a side note I don't think you will need JPA in your pom.xml.